# MagicalRecord crashes on first runtime on ios 8.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

I added CoreData on my project with MagicalRecord, but it crashes on this method:

```
+(NSString *) MR_entityName {
    NSString *entityName;

if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(entityName)])
{
    entityName = [self performSelector:@selector(entityName)];
}

if ([entityName length] == 0)
{
    // Remove module prefix from Swift subclasses
    entityName = [NSStringFromClass(self) componentsSeparatedByString:@"."].lastObject;
}

return entityName;
}
```

on the first if, and in console my entityName is nil. 
Can anybody help me please? @Edit: I added some code and this is what I have right now in console:

```
TestCoreData[483:6632] CoreData: error: -addPersistentStoreWithType:SQLite configuration:(null) URL:file:///Users/macbookpro/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0E01E4C3-42E3-44A1-BE57-2A535715EE03/data/Containers/Data/Application/586065AE-FF44-4396-8999-9E06391595F6/Documents/ options:(null) ... returned error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 256.)" UserInfo=0x7be94450 {NSUnderlyingException=unable to open database file, NSSQLiteErrorDomain=14} with userInfo dictionary {
NSSQLiteErrorDomain = 14;
NSUnderlyingException = "unable to open database file";
```

}

Comment: what type of error does it give?

Comment: In right console where you can write print or whatever, nothing is shown, but I have a Thread1 EXC_BAD_ACCESS in a breakpoint and I can't do anything, just press the stop run button.

Comment: It's bad access and I don't know why and it is happens on the firs if from the method shown.

Comment: add exception breakpoint and try to find out where the the code is crashing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error occurs earlier, not during this method, but you're ignoring the error when it occurs and so you're crashing later on.

The error specifically describes a problem when calling `addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:`, which is a method on `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`. The `Cocoa error 256` part is unfortunately vague but `NSSQLiteErrorDomain` points the finger at problems with your persistent store file.

That problem occurs because the URL you're passing in points to your application's documents directory. You need to pass a path to a file name. The file doesn't have to exist yet, it will be created if needed. But it has to be a path to a file, because Core Data won't make up a file name for you.

This means you're passing in something like `[self applicationDocumentsDirectory]` as the URL. It needs to be a file in that directory, something like `[[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyPersistentStore.sqlite"]`.